# Changing field in Django Form, overriding clean()

Tags: python, json, django, validation, datetime

I have a date, passed as `2019-01-01T00:02`. My objective is to replace the T with a whitespace, `2019-01-01 00:02`.

Using Form, i validate that field and some others.'

```
klientForm = KlientForm(json.loads(request.body.decode()))
bokningForm = BokningForm(json.loads(request.body.decode()))
if klientForm.is_valid() and bokningForm.is_valid():
    #Save model, etc.
```

I'm using `DateTimeField`, and it will not accept the date unless I change it like above. I implemented my own clean() method,

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(BokningForm, self).clean()
    pumpStart = self.data['pumpStart']
    pumpStart = pumpStart.replace("T", " ")
    cleaned_data['pumpStart'] = datetime.strptime(pumpStart, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    return cleaned_data
```

This successfully converts it to a datetime object, I checked using `print(cleaned_data)`

My issue is that the data is returned to late, as (I think) `bokningForm.is_valid()` has already failed, resulting in the model not being saved.

I tried using `clean_pumpStart(self):` as in [Django Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/) but the function was not called when `bokningForm.is_valid()` failed, resulting in the same issue as above.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do any of this. Instead, you should redefine the field itself, supplying the [`input_formats`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.DateTimeField.input_formats) attribute:

```
class BokningForm(forms.ModelForm):
    pumpStart = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'])
    ...
```

Now Django will convert the value automatically as part of its own validation process.

Note, if what you're doing is validating JSON, you probably want to use Django REST Framework and its serializers, rather than plain Django forms.

Answer (score 1):

Clean data is runs before the is_valid, because clean is one of many methods that django runs to validate your form

since you cleaning just one field, use clean to this field

```
class BokningForm(ModelForm)
    ...

    def clean_pumpstart(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['pumpStart']
        data = datetime.strptime(data , "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
        return data
```

in your views maybe this can workout

```
if form.is_valid():
    bokning= form.save(commit=False)
    ... # Change your value
    bokning.save()
```

**EDIT**: Got some good info in other post... try use clean method inside the model, looks like this runs first

```
class Bokning(models.Model):
    def clean(self):
        ...
```

Source: [Django: Model clean method called before form clean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510752/django-model-clean-method-called-before-form-clean)

Comment: The form field will be cleaned before the form's `clean_pumpstart` method is called, so it's too late to change it there.

Comment: its weird... clean functions are supposed to be called before the validations, so you can setup your data before pass to models validations and things arround that